# Bitbucket: Why can't I create a master/x branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

(This is done in SourceTree)

I am trying to make some branches (`master/dev`, `master/demo`, `master/live`) but this cannot be pushed. For example, when I try to push `master/demo` to `master/demo` then it gives this error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master/demo:master/demo
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.

POST git-receive-pack (206 bytes)
remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master/demo': 'refs/heads/master' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/master/demo'        
Pushing to https://x@bitbucket.org/x/x.git
To https://bitbucket.org/x/x.git
 ! [remote rejected] master/demo -> master/demo (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://x@bitbucket.org/x/x.git'



Completed with errors, see above.
```

Answer (score 5):

Internally, branches are stored in `.git/refs/heads` folder as files. If a branch name contains a directory separator, a similar directory is created inside `heads`. The filesystem on the remote prevents you from having a file called `master` and a folder named `master` on the same path, so that's why you get an error.

You need to use something else than `master` as the prefix for your branches.

Comment: Or, equivalently, delete the name `master` as a branch-name. Worth pointing out: Git doesn't always store branch names as files within directories. But it enforces the rules *as if* it did, since it *sometimes* does and doesn't want to deal with any problems when it would convert from the flat `packed-refs` file to the directory-based method.