# error: cannot update the ref <branch>: unable to append to <git location>: Not a directory

Tags: git, github, branch, git-pull

My issue is not [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642836/git-error-unable-to-append-to-git-logs-refs-remotes-origin-master-permission)

On pull, I am getting the following error-

> error: cannot update the ref
>   'refs/remotes/origin/features/name/surname’: unable to append to
>   '.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/features/name/surname': Not a directory

Adding user permissions did not cut any ice.

***Solution***-
Then simply deleting the branch from GitHub resolved the issue.

Interestingly this branch has a different directory structure than other branches.

While other branches look like-

```
refs/remotes/origin/features/name
```

This one looks like-

```
refs/remotes/origin/features/name/surname
```

Comment: This is the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/54229866/1256452, with the same kind of solution: don't try to use both `feature/joe` *and* `feature/joe/smith` as branch names, as Git forbids such a combination.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998832/git-pull-fails-unable-to-resolve-reference-unable-to-update-local-ref/30939030

Answer (score 28):

In your local repo, delete `.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/features/name`.

There is probably a file where it's expecting a directory.

Comment: Thank you! In my case it was the parent directly like `.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/features` that had to go.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. Rather this one did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779012/2190689